# Shopware 6 basic auth exception

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2, shopware, shopware6

I am currently trying to exclude /newsletter from the basic auth but get nothing to work.

Here my current state

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
        <RequireAny>
                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "please login"
                AuthUserFile /my/cool/path/.htpasswd
                Require expr %{THE_REQUEST} =~ m#.*?\s+\/api.*?#
                Require expr %{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^/newsletter.*#
                Require valid-user
        </RequireAny>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "please login"
    AuthUserFile /my/cool/path/.htpasswd
    # Allow access to excluded diretories
    SetEnvIf Request_URI /api noauth=1
    SetEnvIf Request_URI /newsletter noauth=1
    SetEnvIf Request_URI /widgets/checkout/info noauth=1
    Require env noauth
    Require env REDIRECT_noauth
    Require valid-user
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thank you, but does not work for me unfortunately. To add some background: I created a category named newsletter. This page should be visible for customers before the page launches.

Comment: Is the basic auth in general not working or is it only the exclusions not being respected? You changed the `.htaccess` in the `public` directory, right? The above is confirmed to function if set up right.

Comment: Only the exclusions wont work and yes its the `.htaccess`  in public. Maybe I should contact the hoster.